# How do I create a new Leiningen Clojure project in Intellj using the jUnit test runner?

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, clojure, leiningen

I created a new skeleton Leiningen project using `Java 1.8` in `IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.6 (Build #IU-182.5107.16)`.

I got an `Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main`. I wanted to use jUnit instead so I didn't try fix the Cucumber dependency.

**File > Project Stucture > Module**:. Verified that the test folder is marked as Tests.

**File > Project Structure > Libraries > + > From Maven**: Added `junit:junit:4.12` with Transitive dependencies and JavaDocs to my module.

**Run > Edit Configurations**:

- Remove Cucumber Java configuration
- Add jUnit configuration

[image: Run/Debug Configurations for jUnit]

When I run all tests, I am presented with an **Empty test suite** message.

I have tried rebuilding the project, checking for IntelliJ updates, invalidating the cache, using an absolute path in the Working directory in the project configurations modal.

When I run `lein test` in the terminal, the sample test is detected and the assertion is printed out.

Essentially, how do I create a new Leiningen Clojure project in Intellj using the jUnit test runner detects and runs my tests?

*If you need it, I have pushed the [source code](https://github.com/cbillowes/example) of my example project to Github.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

## Update 2020:

I no longer use Leiningen templates to create a new project (e.g. `lein new app XXXXX`).  Instead, I have a template project that I clone using `git`, and I use as the basis for new Clojure and ClojureScript projects:

- [Clojure template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template)
- [ClojureScript template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/cljs-template)

Example of starting a new project:

```
 > git clone https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template.git  myproj
Cloning into 'myproj'...
```

At this point, you can edit the `project.clj` and the source files to change and/or add namespaces, etc.

---

### Old Answer

I don't create projects from within IntelliJ.  I create them at the command line and then add them to IntelliJ/IDEA + Cursive.

```
~/tmp/demo > lein new app sample
Generating a project called sample based on the 'app' template.
~/tmp/demo > cd sample
~/tmp/demo/sample > ls -al
total 56
drwxrwxr-x 6 alan alan  4096 Nov 18 21:19 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 alan alan  4096 Nov 18 21:19 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan   766 Nov 18 21:19 CHANGELOG.md
drwxrwxr-x 2 alan alan  4096 Nov 18 21:19 doc/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan    99 Nov 18 21:19 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan   136 Nov 18 21:19 .hgignore
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan 11219 Nov 18 21:19 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan   359 Nov 18 21:19 project.clj
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan   463 Nov 18 21:19 README.md
drwxrwxr-x 2 alan alan  4096 Nov 18 21:19 resources/
drwxrwxr-x 3 alan alan  4096 Nov 18 21:19 src/
drwxrwxr-x 3 alan alan  4096 Nov 18 21:19 test/
```

Then within IntelliJ do

```
File  ->  New  ->  Project from existing sources....
```

in the pop-up window, navigate to the new dir and double-click on the `project.clj` file.

1. Leave the root dir the same (`~/tmp/demo.sample`)
2. Leave selection as `sample:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT`  (this is taken from `project.clj`)
3. Select your JDK (Java 17 at least, I hope!)
4. Leave the Project Name the same (i.e. `sample`)
5. Click `Finish`

At this point, you can edit `project.clj` to add JUnit deps or anything else you want. This will then determine any mods you need to make in the `./test` subdir tree.

---

After doing

```
lein new app sample
```

you will see in sample/project.clj

```
(defproject sample "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot sample.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

The above is just the bare bones.

For more info, please see:

- [The Clojure Cookbook](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook) and [the print book](http://clojure-cookbook.com/)
- [Living Clojure](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920034292.do)
- [Getting Clojure](https://pragprog.com/book/roclojure/getting-clojure)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I am so new to this I could cry. Any chance you could supply the `project.clj` contents so that I can give this a go a bit later and get back to you?